# Home and End commands in Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard

After installing Lion, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> doesn't go to the line start and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> doesn't go to the line end.

Anyone know how to reconfigure this?

Comment: Hmm… this works for me on a MacBook Pro running Lion. Tried it in TextEdit and BBEdit.

Comment: Which programs is this happening in? It still works for me - though I do prefer using Control-A and Control-E respectively instead.

Comment: at the time I wrote this question it was not working anywhere. Now it's working everywhere, and I did nothing specific :S

Comment: Same for me: it suddenly did not work some time after the Lion upgrade, and a few days later it worked again, without restart or logging off.

Comment: For me, home and end commands work *only* if I highlight the text with Shift key down.

Comment: Same for me: Home and End commands started on their own, without any configuration changes. No software update was ran that would explain this sudden change.

Answer (score 5):

Coming from Windows I've had a tough time adjusting to the way home and end behaves. Luckily the guys at MacroMates had a blog post about this.

http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/

Create a file at `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` with the following contents:

```
{
    /* home */
    "\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";
    "$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";

    /* end */
    "\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";
    "$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";
}
```

I restarted and my keys were behaving as expected!

Answer (score 1):

You could try restoring defaults by using the 'Restore Defaults' button in System Preferences shown below:

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue. But this tip doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Removing ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist.lock and logging out and back in did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was driving me crazy.

Ortwin Gentz wrote:

> Removing ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist.lock and logging out and back in did the trick for me.

I didn't have a file with that name, but I had one with this very similar name:
**~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist**

I moved that file to the trash, then logged out and back in. Problem gone. Hooray!

Thank you, Mr. Gentz!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have something to do with the language you selected.

I had mine set to English - Canadian (eh :P)

setting Language & Text > Input Sources

uncheck English - Canadian 
check US

Once I did that my cmd + arrow key was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Option + Command + right arrow (on the latest Lion update -- it changes)